# Spring Rest Service - Error with 'mvc:annotation-driven'

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, annotations

I tried to integrate rest service to my existing spring mvc 3.0 project but I'm struck with the following error(also tried removing the xsd versions). Please help with this.

"cvc-complex-type.2.4.c: The matching wildcard is strict, but no declaration can be found for element 'mvc:annotation-driven'

Here is my spring XML configuration.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<beans xmlns=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-aop.xsd    
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">



  <mvc:annotation-driven/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.kpp.kpweb.controller" />

    <!--   <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">      
        <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />         
    </bean> 
            --> 



    <bean id="messageSource" class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource"> 
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
                <value>/WEB-INF/springMessages</value>  
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>





    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver">
     <property name="mediaTypes">
       <map>
   <entry key="html" value="text/html"></entry>
   <entry key="json" value="application/json"></entry>
   <entry key="xml" value="application/xml"></entry>
 </map>
     </property>
     <property name="viewResolvers">
 <list>
  <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView">
            </property>
     <property name="prefix" value="/jsp/"></property>
     <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"></property>
   </bean>
 </list>
     </property>
  </bean> 



</beans>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you can't figure out your mistakes from the first answer I gave, just replace your xsi:schemaLocation with this

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd    
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
     http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
```

Answer (score 0):

Your **schemaLocation** declarion is incorrect.

Instead of

```
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-aop.xsd    
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
```

Use

```
xsi:schemaLocation=" http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-aop.xsd    
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd 
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd"
```

Comment: Now I get the below error.                                                                                 
 " org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet initServletBean Context initialization failed    Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionStoreException: Line 14 in XML document from ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/spring-config.xml] is invalid; nested exception is org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: cvc-elt.1: Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'. "

Comment: You are missing a double quote in xmlns=http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"

Comment: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: SchemaLocation: schemaLocation value = ' http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.0.xsd              http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-aop.xsd                 http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx.xsd              http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd' must have even number of URI's

Answer (score 0):

Your aop xsd location is wrong. Please correct it. It should be

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop.xsd
```

And not

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-aop.xsd
```

Then the mvc xsi:schemaLocation should be

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd"
```

And not

```
http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc-3.1.xsd"
```

I hope this help

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

  xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd    
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-aop.xsd  
         http://www.springframework.org/schema/context  
            http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

Comment: Tried with almost all combinations for the xsd versions. Getting the same error.
When I tried with the below answer by Sundararaj Govindasamy, I get the error 'Cannot find the declaration of element 'beans'

Is there something to do with the jar files. All my spring dependency jars are of version *.3.1.0